# Can I get the File after FileStream.openAsync(File...)?

Tags: actionscript-3, file, filestream

In the `COMPLETE` event listener of `FileStream.openAsync(file, ...);` `FileStream.read(...)`, can I get the File object that the FileStream was opened with?

Comment: take a look at the docs to find available methods. eg: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#openAsync()

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the `File` object that the `FileStream` is opening, inside the event handler function of the `FileStream`'s `COMPLETE` event?

As far as I know this isn't possible. You can get the `FileStream` object that is opening the file:

```
private function completeHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    var stream:FileStream = e.target as FileStream;
}
```

But unfortunately there's no way to get the `File` object that the `FileStream` is opening, not even the path.

Your best bet is to extend the scope of the `File` object in question, i.e. declare it outside of a function so that all functions can access it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up sub-classing the FileStream object, overriding the openAsyc() and open(), then saving the File parameter to a public property.

No even inelegant, but I wanted to ensure that I had not overlooked some existing property.

Cheers